# Singleplatform & Foursquare API

Tags: php

I have list of restaurant details along with menus which i got from singleplatform. Now I want to get the reviews and checkin details from Foursquare. But I have noticed some samples on foursquare & it uses a VENUE-ID to get the checkins. Is it possible to use the id that I got form singleplatform as VENUE ID? Or is there any way that I can integrate both the API's to get Restaurant Name, Menu list of the respective restaurants, reviews and checkin?

Note: I am newbie PHP developer.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the reviews and checkin details from Foursquare, you'll need to call their Venue-ID in their Venues Platform.

In order to map the SinglePlatform ID to the Foursquare Venue ID, you'll need to use their venue harmonization tool. You can learn more about it here: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/mapping

Hope this helps.